# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission

Tags: java, android, zxing

tryng to integrate zxing in my app.

This is the gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.machinarius:preferencefragment:0.1.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.16'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'

}
```

And this is the ScanActivity.class

```
package it.xxx.views;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;

/**
 * Created by Alessandro on 11/01/2016.
 */
public class ScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new IntentIntegrator(this).initiateScan(); // `this` is the current Activity

    }
}
```

But I get APP crash and in log:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission
```

Thank you for your support!

Comment: import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;  where are you using this import in your activity?

Comment: I did add this as seen in another question, but it didn't help. In effect via Android Studio is in grey, it is not used...

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'  add this dependency